# Using GPIO in webpage

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

I am using Django 1.5.4 to design a web page in which i want to use GPIO, but i got following error:

"Noﾠaccessﾠtoﾠ/dev/mem. Tryﾠrunningﾠasﾠroot! "

in browser. Since web browser itself is an application, how can i assign "root" privileges to it when it tried to render a web page ? If it can be done without any need to install anything that would be better as other frameworks/applications who are able to use GPIO in web page must have made some tweaks.I tried searching for similar questions for this area but couldn't find this specific case ( django + gpio access).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No.... not the browser. The web server. It needs to be running as root (make sure you understand what django is - it's server-side.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to run the webbrowser as root but your django app (the webserver).

Of course running a web application as root is an incredibly bad idea (even on a pi), so you might want to use a separate worker process (e.g. using celery) that runs as root and accesses the GPIOs.

Comment: nice thinking ! i have run django webserver with sudo. still i got the same error :(

Comment: i ran all django webserver, idle (to edit the server web page) & dillo (web browser) with root. still getting the same error !!

Comment: Did you verify it's running as root or did you just assume it to be the case?

Comment: ya..i did that verification. Django server is running as root! The problem when i tried to use GPIO.input(), i got this error. Isn't there separate way to achieve the same without using this method ?